# How to create a list of objects from multiple input fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a form using HTML and CSS, and I want to store all the input values in the form in an object, then add the object to a list of objects, serving as a database for all the "users" of this form, with all their information of course. here's what I tried already:

```
signupbtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
addObject();
HideSignUpPage();
});

let objects = [];

function addObject(){
var firstname = document.getElementById("firstnamebox").value; 
var lastname = document.getElementById("lastnamebox").value;
var emailornumber = document.getElementById("emailornumberbox").value;
var password = document.getElementById("passwordbox").value;
var month = document.getElementById("monthbox").value;
var year = document.getElementById("yearbox").value;
var day = document.getElementById("daybox").value;
var gender;
var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName("gender");
for (let i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++){
    if (radiobuttons[i].checked){
        gender = radiobuttons[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
var obj = {
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
    emailornumber: emailornumber,
    password: password,
    month: month,
    year: year,
    day: day,
    gender: gender
};

objects.push(obj)
}

document.getElementById("objects").innerHTML = objects
```

for some reason, when I try to print out the objects list with a document.write, it prints out "undefined". even tho I have submitted the form multiple times so theoretically it should've filled the array with a bunch of objects.

Comment: where is the html, where is the `document.write`? please provide [mcve] with input, expected vs actual output

Comment: Where do you use `document.write`, and where is `objects` defined?

Comment: added the document.write and objects, as for the html, it's just a normal form box so i figured its not important to include

Comment: @HomamMurad but now you are writing `objects` before populating it.

Comment: @JanPfeifer am I supposed to initialize the array after adding elements to it? logically I thought that I should create an empty array first before adding anything to it..

Comment: @HomamMurad No, if I am seeing corectly: you are assigning click handler, then you define `objects` array,  then you define `addObject function` and then immediately writing `objects` array to some `HTML` element. `objects` array is empty at the time.

Comment: @JanPfeifer so what is the correct order? i'm confused

Comment: @Homam You are writing it immediately after declaring it, so it is empty. Use `console.log(objects)` in your `click` listener.